# Can I provide localized CHM files for an MMC 3.0 snap-in on Windows 2003?

Tags: mmc, mmc3

I am developing a MMC 3.0 snap-in using C#. I would like my snap-in to automatically localize itself according to the current language, i.e. on a Spanish OS, the snap-in should display in Spanish and should use a Spanish help file.

Since my snap-in is a .NET application, GUI localisation is no problem. However, I am having trouble with the localisation of my HTML Help (CHM) file. I want to deploy several localised CHM files to disk, and for MMC to choose the appropriate CHM file to display at run-time.

At the moment, my snap-in launches the English version of my CHM file, which is defined in the "HelpTopic" and "LinkHelpTopics" registry values under HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\<snapin-guid>. I have found [an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692743(VS.85).aspx) that suggests that I can provide localised versions of this CHM file in a mui\<language-code> directory, e.g. (for Spanish) mui\3082\file.chm.

When I try this on Windows 2008, it works - the Spanish version of the help file appears. But when I try it on Windows 2003, I still get the English help file.

Does anyone know if this is a limitation of MMC 3.0 on Windows 2003? If so, what is the best way to achieve what I want to do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up on this - I haven't found any evidence that this is possible. There is [another article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277604(VS.85).aspx) that describes how to override MMC's help system and use your own arbitrary mechanism to display help, but this requires users to download a hotfix, and works only on Windows 2008, so is no help for this particular problem.

In the end what I have decided to do is install a single CHM file and reference that in the registry; but that CHM file may be the English version, Spanish version, etc, depending on the user's Windows locale at the time of the install.